# Mail Masivos en Asp.net y SQL

Tags: asp.net

me encuentro realizando un aplicativo en asp.net el cual debe rescatar datos los cuales tienen una fecha, los cuales si cumplen con una inactividad de 180 días se le debe enviar un mail. El problema es que la BD tiene 3.2 Millones de Datos por ende podría mandar 3.2 millones de Mail, he intentado mandar 300 mail y me funciona, pero cuando intento mandar 1000 mail me sale error.

> Error System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: El buzón de correo no está
> disponible. La respuesta del servidor fue: 5.2.2 Submission quota
> exceeded en
> System.Net.Mail.DataStopCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode
> statusCode, String serverResponse)

```
try
                    {
                        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mensaje = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

                        string Destinatario = "mail@gmail.cl";//txtPara.Text;
                        string Asunto = "Notificación de Recepción Oficina Parte Virtual";
                        ///Cambiar

                        mensaje.To.Add(Destinatario);
                        mensaje.Subject = Asunto;
                        mensaje.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                        
                        mensaje.Body = "El documento ha sido recepcionado de forma exitosa. " + "<br />" + "<br />" +
                                       "Para: " + lblPara.Text + "<br />" +
                                       "Copia: " + lblCopia.Text + "<br />" +
                                       "Fiscalia: " + lblFi.Text + "<br />" +
                                       " Oriente";
                        mensaje.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                        mensaje.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        mensaje.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("mail@gmail.cl");

                        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient Cliente = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                        Cliente.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail@gmail.cl", "XXXXXX");

                        Cliente.Port = 25;
                        Cliente.EnableSsl = false;

                        Cliente.Host = "exchange.cl"; //mail.dominio.com
                        Cliente.Send(mensaje);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Response.Write(ex);
                    }
```

Comment: A tener en cuenta: 1. El SMTP de Gmail tiene una capacidad de envío diaria, con 300 no se te va de las manos según lo que veo, funciona bien para micro-empresa y pequeña empresa que mandan poquísimo volumen de correo. 2. Para la enorme cantidad de correos a enviar, vas a tener que hacer 1 de 2 cosas: A) Levantar tu propio servidor de correo con tu dominio y rogar a los dioses del Olimpo para mantengan tu dominio en la lista de dominios aceptable y eviten caer en las listas de spam... B) Utilizar un 3rd party como Mailgun y de acuerdo a su calculadora en https://www.mailgun.com/pricing/

Comment: la gracia le puede costar a la empresa la módica suma de 1250$ USD mensuales aproximadamente en caso se envíen los 3.2 millones de correos. Otra alternativa es SendGrid (adquirida por Twilio) https://sendgrid.com/pricing/ donde por 1 millón de correos enviados al mes, va por los 449$ USD.

Comment: Ahora bien, ¿puedes sacar una estadística de la cantidad de correos de usuarios inactivos que existen? ¿Es necesario enviar el correo de un solo tiro? ¿Cada cuánto tiempo debería re-enviarse el correo desde la primera vez que se envía? ¿Monitoreas si el correo llegó debidamente o si lanzó un ilustre failure?

Comment: ¿Alguna actualización de este escenario?